# Send php mail using html webform

Tags: php, html, email, webforms, sendmail

I have set up a page that is still in construction and i'm building a webform for users to contact me.

When i fill the webform and hit the "send" button, message gets send succesfully and i receieve it on my mail...but when i hit the "send" button, i get re-directed off page, saying it was sent successfully.

How can i prompt user that the message was sent successfully, without getting redirected of page, and get the message in same window?

**This is my HTML code**

```
<form action="assets/php/contactUs.php" id="contact" class="form" role="form" method="post">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 form-group">
          <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" required />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 form-group">
          <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" required />
        </div>
      </div>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message" rows="5"></textarea>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
          <button class="btn btn btn-lg">Send Message</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

**And this is my contactUs.php code**

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$message = <<<EMAIL

$message

From: $name

My email is: $email

EMAIL;

$to = "mymail@mymail.com";
$subject = "New Customer Enquiry";

mail($to, $subject, $message, "From: " . $email);
echo "Thank you, your message has been successfully sent!";

?>
```

**AJAX**

```
<script        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('.btn-lg').click(function(){
$.post( "assets/php/contactUs.php", $( "#contact" ).serialize(),     function(msg){
    alert(msg);
} );
});
});
</script>
```

This is a result of successfully sent message.

[image: Error]

**Please guys help me out!** Thanks!

**REDIRECT OPTION**

```
$firstpageurl = 'http://example.com';
echo "Your message has been successfully sent!";
$header('Location: '.$firstpageurl);
```

Comment: In order to accomplish a dialog like you wish, you will need to use javascript with ajax that submits your POST data instead of doing a full page load

Comment: you get redirected because of your form `action`.  You could consider using [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: isn't there any easier option? i'm really bad with javascript and i still have so much to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Ajax as below.Change the submit type button to a normal button by removing the type attribute.

```
<script        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('.btn-lg').click(function(event){
$.post( "config.php", $( "#contact" ).serialize(),     function(msg){
    alert(msg);
} );
event.preventDefault();
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you this works, but after that i still get redirect to "assets/php/contactUs.php" and get the same message again.

Comment: Did you change your button - remove the type attribute:
    <button class="btn btn btn-lg">Send Message</button>

Comment: yes sir i did. Do i have to change anything in my .php file? We'll i'll just post my edited code so you can have a better look at it

Comment: You dont need to change anything in .php. Post your updated code here

Comment: you can take a look at it

Comment: See my updated code

If still doesn' t work then send me a link where you re implementing this

Comment: I had to change "config.php" to my actual name but yeah it works now. Strange though, suddenly the sender is now "unknown sender" and message is empty" That didn't happen before and my .php code is still the same

Comment: with a bit od tweeking i have finally solved the problem. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The action part of your form tag is "assets/php/contactUs.php"

```
<form action="assets/php/contactUs.php" id="contact" class="form" role="form" method="post">
```

That means that posting this form will bring you to that page.  You can either code that page to send the email and redirect them back like this...

```
header('Location: '.$firstpageurl);
```

or put the php code into this first page and remove the entire action property.  If you put the php on this page, you need to wrap your code in an if so that people can load the page before posting the form.

```
    if (isset($_POST['email'])){
      echo "Sent email";
      [email send code here]
    }
```

as for putting the message saying it's sent...that will only work with the second method. To do it without a full page load at all do it with ajax.

Comment: The "redirect choice" seems easier to me. But somehow i dont get redirected. Anything bad with my code? Can you please look @ the edited post. And sorry im new to php (actually started 2 hours ago) so i'm really newb at it.

Comment: You have echoed some text before your redirect.  That means php has sent headers, then echoed text.  You need to put your redirect before any text has been written, and that includes an empty line with just a carriage return.  One common workaround if you must tell people that they've submitted the form, it to make another special page with that thank you message and redirect them there, and on that page make it easy for them to click back to the original content page.   It sounds like you're using a cms and can't have php on you content pages?

Comment: Another workaround is to build your php page like I said in option 2 with an if.  And from your cms put an iframe pointing to your form.  Then you can have your success message.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use JQuery for that.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
$("#contact").submit(function(){
    var form_data=$("form").serialize();
    $.post( "assets/php/contactUs.php",form_data, function( data ) {
        alert(data);
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Comment: does it alert you after clicking the send button?

Comment: nope, i get stuck at empty "assets/php/contactUs.php" page

Comment: also remove '$header('Location: '.$firstpageurl);' in your php file.

Comment: i have no idea why isn't it working then. have u checked out my html code?

Comment: do i need type submit in my button or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without using Javascript. Do the following:

1. Set the form to post to itself (e.g. if your form was on index.php, set `action="index.php"`
2. When the page loads, check `$_POST` to see if the form values were sent.
3. If the `$_POST` values are empty, display the form
4. If the `$_POST` values are set, do what you need to do with those values, then output your results into the page.

Here's a really simple example demonstrating what I mean.

```
<?php
  $submitted = false;

  if (isset($_POST["myinput"]) && $_POST["myinput"] != '') {
    $submitted = true;
  }
?>
<?php
  if ($submitted == false) {
?>
  <form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input name="myinput"><input type="submit">
  </form>
<?php } else { ?>
  <h1>Form Submitted</h1>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your input, but i have solved problem with other solution. hopefully yours will help some1 else some day.